# Compile errors with MagicalRecord in Swift

Tags: swift, magicalrecord

I'm trying to compile a test project using MagicalRecord library with Swift language and I'm getting those errors when compile.

I've created the bridging file and import the library but it doesn't works... What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to go to the MagicalRecord.h file and add this line of code to the very top:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Here is the file:

[image]

This fixed the problem for me. Remember that it needs to be the first line so that everything else compiles correctly. I had to do this in the latest version released on Github.

Hopefully, the creator will fix this soon.